# Using PostgreSQL to combine two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables inside PostgreSQL that I want to combine. They look like this:

```
A     B
--------
a     0
b     1
c     2
```

```
A
---
a
b
d
```

I want to result of the "combine" operation to look like the following:

```
A     B
--------
a     0
b     1
-     2
d     -
```

How do I accomplish this in postgres and also pure SQL? It seems that none of the `JOIN` operations quite accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `full join`:

```
select t2.a, t1.b
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.a = t2.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Full outer join:

```
SELECT t2.a,
  t1.b
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.a = t2.a
```

---

For more:

- http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-full-outer-join.php
- https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/joins.php